# does window.location.href have server specific behavior?

Tags: javascript, android

I've got a site that's relatively simple. The user performs some action on the page, and some javascript runs... after it runs, it calls:

> window.location.href = window.location.href;

... to refresh the page.

It seemed to work fine, tested in android emulator's browser.

However, when QA deploys in their environment, it's not... the page doesn't reload. There's no querystring or anything of that sort, mostly just static html and javascript/jquery.

I've used my emulator to test mine and the qa site as well as qa's emulator to test both. In both circumstances, it's just the qa server that exhibits this problem... I've also used a normal desktop browser to test both sites (ie, chrome, ff), and the behavior is consistent.

So, I'm wondering, is there anything on the server that could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: JavaScript runs client-side; so it's related to the browser, not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.reload(true);` instead. This forces the page to be reloaded from the server. Your code can result in the behavior that the browser caches the page and doesn't fetch the page from the server again.

Answer (score 2):

Why not this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

The `true` argument forces a reload (without using the browser cache).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: Thanks Lucero... I accepted DominikGuzei's answer cause he answered at the same time and it was just as correct, but it looks like he could use some rep :)

Comment: @SnOrfus, I posted my answer more than 2 minutes earlier (you can see the exact time as tooltip when hovering above the "answered ..." text)... but OK for the rep. ;)